# Python error with QFileDialog using pyqt5 library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create a path browser in pyqt5 using python3 but I have some doubts. My code is this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets    
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
            MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 150, 160, 80))
            self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
            self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
            self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
            self.label.setObjectName("label")
            self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
            self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
            self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
            self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
            self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
            self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
            self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton)
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

            # Button action
            self.toolButton.pressed.connect(self.selectDirectory(MainWindow, self.lineEdit))
        def selectDirectory(self, MainWindow, editText):

                editText.setText(str(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(MainWindow, "Select Directory", str(editText.text()))))

        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
            self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Path"))
            self.toolButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The idea was using a edittext to write the path to the folder but as helper I want to introduce a button to open a file browser in order to select the directory. To achive this I am trying to use QFileDialog without success. My problem at this moment is when I run my application the QFileDialog is displayed and when I choose a folder the application crash. The first thing I do not want to display the QFileDialog without press the button and the second thing I do not understand why the application is crashing with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 48, in <module>
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
  File "test.py", line 31, in setupUi
    self.toolButton.pressed.connect(self.selectDirectory(MainWindow, self.lineEdit))
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signal `pressed` hopes to connect to a slot that does not expect arguments, so you can not do the direct connection with the `selectDirectory()` function, you must make the connection using a lambda function.

You must change

```
self.toolButton.pressed.connect(self.selectDirectory(MainWindow, self.lineEdit))
```

to

```
self.toolButton.pressed.connect(lambda m=MainWindow, l=self.lineEdit: self.selectDirectory(m, l))
```